# Woocommerce related products not randomizing

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product

I have issue with related products in Woocommerce, every time I refresh the page, there are exactly same products in random order. Could you please advice code modification, which will cause showing random products from category?

```
if (!function_exists('woocommerce_output_related_products')) {
// Number of related products
function woocommerce_output_related_products() {
    woocommerce_related_products(array(
        'posts_per_page' => 8,
        'columns' => 4,
        'orderby' => 'rand',
    )); // Display 4 products in rows of 1
}
}
```

Comment: what plugins do you have installed?

Comment: First, I'd strongly recommend doing this through the filter 'woocommerce_output_related_products_args' rather than in the function directly. That will get overwritten as soon as you update WooCommerce.

The most likely suspect for why this ignoring the random query is that you have a caching plugin enabled. Check to see if that's the case, and if so, disable it and try loading the page again.